# SQL: Query new rows of a new date

Tags: sql

i have table as shown here in this picture --> http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3710/lj7etq5j_png.htm

I need the correct Query to get only data_id 10.

The query should be like this: Compare the latest date rows (2014-08-08) with the earliest date rows (2014-08-06). If there is a row on 2014-08-08 which is NOT at 2014-08-06, this row should returned.

I already tried it with self-joins and Sub-Selects, but i did't get it work.

Thx for any help!

Comment: You posted your table on a site with Ads and popup. Quite annoying!

Comment: it seems that `nextTableId` must be unique in this table then

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

```
select * from Table1
where 
    data not in (
        select data from Table1 
        where dataOfDate = (select min(dataofdate) from Table1)
        )
    and dataOfDate = (select max(dataofdate) from Table1)
```

The first where clause compares the data field of the returned rows to the data field in the set of oldest rows and the second where clause limits the set of rows the the newest.

Note that I'm only comparing rows based on the`data`field, so you might have to change the query if you want to include`nextTableId`in the comparison.

[Here is a sample SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76aa8/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
SELECT d1.* FROM Dates d1 LEFT JOIN Dates d2 ON d1.nextTableId = d2.nextTableId WHERE d1.dataofDate = '2014-08-08' AND d2.dataofDate = '2014-08-06' AND d2.data_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `data_id`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `dataOfDate` = (SELECT MAX(`dataOfDate`) FROM `my_table`)
AND `nextTableId` NOT IN (
    SELECT `nextTableId` FROM `my_table` WHERE `dataOfDate` = (SELECT MIN(`dataOfDate`) FROM `my_table`) 
)
```

1. select all rows with max date
2. that don't have values amongst rows with min date

**edit** ops, too late